# Fail to store values to the list

Tags: c++, list

It seems the attribute `test aisbn` is successfully storing the data invoking `setCode()`, `setDigit()`. But The trouble starts failing while I attempt these values to store into `list<test> simul`

The list attribute takes the value of digit after `setDigit()` but the code. How can I put both code and digit into the list attribute? I can't see where the problem is. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    private:
        string code;
        int digit;

    public:
        //constructor
        test(): code(""), digit(0) { }

        //copy constructor
        test(const test &other):
        digit(other.digit)
        { 
            for(unsigned int i=0; i < code.length(); i++)   
                code[i] = other.code[i];
        }

        //set up the private values 
        void setCode(const string &temp, const int num);
        void setCode(const string &temp);
        void setDigit(const int &num);


        //return the value of the pointer character 
        const string &getCode() const;
        const unsigned int getDigit() const;
};

const string& test::getCode() const
{
    return code;
}
const unsigned int test::getDigit() const
{
    return digit;
}
void test::setCode(const string &temp, const int num)   
{
    if((int)code.size() <= num)
    {
        code.resize(num+1);
    }
    code[num] = temp[num];
}
void test::setCode(const string &temp)  
{
    code = temp;
}
void test::setDigit(const int &num)
{
    digit = num;
}


int main()
{
    const string contents = "dfskr-123";

    test aisbn;
    list<test> simul;
    list<test>::iterator testitr;
    testitr = simul.begin();
    int count = 0;

    cout << contents << '\n';
    for(int i=0; i < (int)contents.length(); i++)
    {
        aisbn.setCode(contents);
        aisbn.setDigit(count+1);
        simul.push_back(aisbn);
        count++;
    }
    cout << contents << '\n';

    /*for(; testitr !=simul.end(); simul++)
    {
        cout << testitr->getCode() << "\n";
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are having issues with your `for` loop, you need to modify your `for` loop like so:

```
for(testitr = simul.begin(); testitr !=simul.end(); testitr++)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

although, `push_back` does not invalidate iterators for `std::list` I think it is more readable to set the iterator where you are using it. Based on your response you also need to modify the `copy constructor`:

```
test(const test &other): code(other.code), digit(other.digit) {}
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: forget the for loop. What I wonder is that simul.push_back(aisbn) only takes the value of the digit from setDigit(). Could you look into the code for(int i=0; i < (int)contents.length(); i++)
  {
   aisbn.setCode(contents);
   aisbn.setDigit(count+1);
   simul.push_back(aisbn);
   count++;
  }

Comment: @user2282596 Modified answer

Answer (score 0):

how about using the `vector`

```
std::vector<test> simul;

 for(int i=0; i < (int)contents.length(); i++)
    {
        aisbn.setCode(contents);
        aisbn.setDigit(count+1);
        simul.push_back(aisbn);
        count++;
    }
```

iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.
Otherwise, only the last iterator is invalidated.

Comment: I should've used vector early if can. Using list is compulsory :)